# How to refactor this for loop? Check if tag id matches tag in Array, then update its border

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, refactoring

```
function deselectColoredTag(tag) {
    // Check for selected Tag:
    for (var i=0; i<vm.tags.length; i++) {
        if (vm.tags[i].term_id === tag.term_id) {
            if (vm.tags[i].border1) {
                vm.tags[i].border1 = false;
                break;
            }
            if (vm.tags[i].border2) {
                vm.tags[i].border2 = false;
                break;
            }
            if (vm.tags[i].border3) {
                vm.tags[i].border3 = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code above will loop through and check if the tag exists in `vm.tags` if so, check if it has border1, border2, or border3 and set it to false.

I wanted to avoid doing this:

```
border1 = false;
border2 = false;
border3 = false;
```

And make it a bit smarter, I also tried the following however it did not work:

```
for (var i=0; i<vm.tags.length; i++) {
    for(var j=0; j<3; j++){
        if (vm.tags[i].term_id === tag.term_id) {
            if (vm.tags[i].border[j]) {
                vm.tags[i].border[j] = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

This errors out for some reason:

`if (vm.tags[i].border[j])`

**TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined** However this is just a basic truthy text, correct? Does `vm.tags[1].border[0]` exist for example...

Comment: You have `border1` and not `border.1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach should be like this:

```
for (var i=0; i<vm.tags.length; i++) {
    for(var j=0; j<3; j++){
        if (vm.tags[i].term_id === tag.term_id) {
            if (vm.tags[i]['border' + j]) {
                vm.tags[i]['border' + j] = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I forget that from time to time

Answer (score 1):

enumerated properties, never a good sign. 
why don't you use an Array for the borders?

```
mainLoop: for(var i=0, l<vm.tags.length; i<l; ++i){
    var currentTag = vm.tags[i];
    if(currentTag.term_id !== tag.term_id) continue;
    for(var i=0; i<3; ++i){
        if(currentTag['border'+i]){
            currentTag['border'+i] = false;
            break mainLoop;
        }
    }
}
```